# Allow custom annotation only one one method per class

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

I have a annotation `@ToolExecution`. At the moment I use annotation processing and throwing `Error` to ensure that only **one** method is annotated with this annotation.

Is there an native way to create a constraint and allow my custom annotation to be only applied to one annotation per class?

### This should not be possible

```
@Tool(id = "scheduledtool")
public class ScheduledTool extends SimpleTool {
  private String parameter;

  @ToolExecution
  public void configuration(@ToolParameters(fields = {"config"}, credentials = true) ToolParameter parameters) {
    String parameter = parameters.getParameter("config");
    this.parameter = parameter;
  }

  @ToolExecution
  public void execute() {
    toolLog(Level.INFO, "Configured Param: " + parameter);
    toolLog(Level.INFO, "Finished scheduled tool");
  }

}
```

Comment: You can't enforce a single method annotation per class at compile time, you can only do that type of validation at runtime.

Comment: You should learn [Annotation Processor](https://medium.com/@iammert/annotation-processing-dont-repeat-yourself-generate-your-code-8425e60c6657)

Comment: @lance-java pls define an answer to close this question

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce a single method annotation per class at compile time, you can only do that type of validation at runtime.